# Regex to print contents between dynamic word and a comma

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list and if I find a word in line matching list,then the dynamic word is passed to regex to print between that word and the first comma (`,`).

```
keyword=[car,bike,bus]
```

Text file:

```
I want a car Mercedes Benz,but its costly,and high maintenence.
```

Then output should be:

```
Mercedes Benz
```

I tried this code to pass the found keyword as a input:

```
keywords=['car','bike','bus'] 

with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:            
        matches = []
        for word in line.split():
            if word in keywords:
                l=line
                matches.append(word)            
        if matches:
            a = ' '.join(matches)
            TEXT = a
            my_regex = r"\b(?=\w)" + re.escape(TEXT) + r"\b(?!\,)"   
            x = re.findall(my_regex, l)    

        else:
            print 'nil'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\b\s*(.*?),'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))))
>>> r.findall(s)
['Mercedes Benz']
>>> s = "I want a car Mercedes Benz,but its costly, so I'll get car Volkswagen Beetle, as it is cheap."
>>> r.findall(s)
['Mercedes Benz', 'Volkswagen Beetle']
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex like so:

```
my_regex = r"\b" +re.escape(TEXT) + r"\s*([ \w]+)(?=,)"
```

Comment: Thanks!could u edit my entire code,because its taking some time!

Comment: @user3914506: I didn't test it, but this is probably the only edit you'll need. After applying this regex with `re.findall()`, you can just loop through them and print the matches. But as you can see, Ashwini Chaudhary's solution is more elegant — I suggest you use that approach. Cheers!